# How to write a novel which is taking place entirely in a foreign country, with foreign culture and foreign characters?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, science-fiction, historical-fiction

How to write a novel which is taking place entirely in a foreign country, with a foreign culture and foreign characters?

Comment: I'd recomend writing in in Microsoft Word, but Google Docs is good too, especially if you see your self writing on different computers (Hint:  Why not tell us about your stumbling blocks and even the foreign country you specifically want to use... this is a very broad question with a very broad range of answers).

Comment: Yes I agree with hszmv, this is a very broad question, can you narrow it down just a tad please? Do you have trouble with locations, accents, physical appearance, or something else?

Comment: This is a VERY broad question (I agree with the two users above), but I would say that if you are a person who has never been to that country and you don't know how to explain it properly, you CAN'T write it. If it's a fantasy world, however, go ahead and write it! You would be the only person who has "experienced" the country so you could write it.

Comment: "Hans looked over Berlin, seeing the Eiffel Tower's pointed shape casting a shadow over Trafalgar Square".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but I try to answer it depending on how I interpreted it.

I too, sometimes struggle with writing cultures, characters, and countries. The best tool you have is **Research**. In order to write about foreign traditions and people, you need to understand them first.

In these pandemic times - you most likely will not be able to find and talk with someone familiar with the culture of interest. So, your second best thing to do is research the culture and people. You can do this online, or you check out books on the wanted subject.

You should learn as much as you can - **even information that you don't think you will need**. You never know if you might need it. And, the more true information on the foreign country you have, the more authentic your book will seem.

If it is safe for you - I would highly recommend meeting someone from the foreign country, or anyone with knowledge of the specific country or region.

The best way, however - would be (if it's safe) to travel to the country and get personal, first-hand experience, which will greatly help you.

After gathering your information - you need to write your story! Make sure to be respectful when writing about your culture. Be realistic and include as many relevant facts as possible.

Hope this helps!